# Python - Receiving an TypeError

Tags: python-3.x

So the code below:
Takes a given square, and if it is an X does nothing. If the square has an O in it, it changes the O to an X and autofills the square above, below, to the left, and to the right.

```
#openFile(filename): This function opens and prints the users txt file for paint
#input: none
#output: The file that needs to be painted 
def openFile(filename):

    file = open(filename, 'r')

    for line in file:

        print(line)

    file.close()


#convertFile(filename): This function is used to convert the .txt file into a 2D arrary
#input: none
#output: none
def convertFile(filename):

     empty = []


    filename = open(filename, 'r')


    for line in filename:

        line = line.rstrip("\n")

        empty.append(list(line))

    return empty


#getCoordinates(x,y): This function is used to get the coordinates the user wants to pain from
#input: user coordinates.
#output: none
def getCoordinates(x, y):

    coordinates = []

    userInt = 0

    user = []

    try:

        user = input("Please enter a square to fill , or q to exit: ")

        user.split()

        coordinates.append(int(user[0]))
        coordinates.append(int(user[2]))

    except ValueError:

        print("Enter a valid input!")

        user = input("Please enter a square to fill, or q to exit: ")

        user.split()

        coordinates.append(int(user[0]))
        coordinates.append(int(user[2]))

    return coordinates



def printGrid(grid):

    for innerList in grid:
        for item in innerList:
            print(item, end = "")
        print()




#autoFill(board, row, col): This is the heart of the program and the recursive program
# use to fill the board with x's
#input: none
#output: none
def autoFill(grid, rows, cols):
    if grid[cols][rows] == "X":
        return 0
    else:
        grid[cols][rows] = "X"
        if rows > 0:
            autoFill(grid, rows - 1, cols)

        if rows < len(grid[cols]) - 1:
            autoFill(grid, rows + 1, cols)

        if cols > 0:
            autoFill(grid, rows, cols - 1)

        if cols < len(grid) - 1:
            autoFill(grid, rows, cols + 1)







def main():



    coordinates = [] 

    empty = []

    while True:

        filename = input("Please enter a filename: ")

        openFile(filename)

        empty = convertFile(filename)


        coordinates = getCoordinates(len(empty), len(empty[0]))

        empty = autoFill(empty(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]))



        for item in empty:

            s = ""
            s.join(item)

            for x in item:

                s += str(x)
            print(s)


    if user == "q":

        return 0



main()
```

output should look like:

```
Please enter a filename: input.txt
OOOOOOXOOOO
OOOOOXOOOOO
OOOOXOOOOOO
XXOOXOOOOOO
XXXXOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOO
Please enter a square to fill, or q to exit: 1, 1
XXXXXXXOOOO
XXXXXXOOOOO
XXXXXOOOOOO
XXXXXOOOOOO
XXXXOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOO
```

But when i type in the coordinate points i get:

```
empty = autoFill(empty(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Any guidance in fixing this issue will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The particular error you're asking about is happening because you're trying to call `empty` (which is a `list`, as returned by `convertFile`) as if it were a function.